# How do I post to a friend's Timeline using the Android SDK using FacebookDialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working with the facebook SDK and attempting to post things to a friend's timeline. I am able to post to my own timeline without any problem, but the minute I choose someone else's it errors out.

After doing some research, it seems like the problem is deprecated API related and now you must "mention" them in your post to tag them. This is all fine and dandy, BUT, the issue is, the facebook SDK still allows them to choose that option:

[image: Post Something]
[image: Option Still exists]
[image: Choose Friend]
[image: Error Happens]

As a result of this, it gives a toast error and then pops up something in the notification bar which does an endless loop of "try again" and failing constantly. This gives the impression to the user that I did not program it correctly, when it is a facebook issue...

Does anyone have any recommendations or ideas on how to eliminate the option to share with friends or hide it? Thanks!

-Silmarilos

Comment: Fair Enough. Which share method would you recommend using then? FeedDialog? Or something else entirely?

Comment: It is not possible to post on a friends timeline using the API at all. No way. Impossible

Comment: @WizKid really? Because I'm trying it since last few days.

Comment: I can't even send message from app without having Messenger. Do you have any idea to post/send message?

Comment: You can't. You have to use messenger